# xlwings - This workbook contains links to other data sources - display_alert doesn't work

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

Intention is to refresh an entire workbook with links to another workbook.
The code below results in a popup window where there is a choice between updating links or not.
Is there a way to remove this popup? Currently **app.display_alerts = False** doesn't work.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App()
app.display_alerts = False
wb = xw.Book('pathToFile')
wb.api.RefreshAll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `update_links=False` when opening a workbook. This works for both `xw.Book()` as well as `myapp.books.open()`:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('pathToFile', update_links=False)
wb.api.RefreshAll()
```

Unless you need to open your book in a specific `app`, you don't need to explicitly instantiate an `app` object. You could also get ahold of it via `wb.app`, only that for this scenario, you won't need it.

Comment: could you help with the syntax below. As the post says I want to refresh links and update pivots.
import xlsings as xw
wb = xw.Book('pathToFile', update_links=False)
wb.api.RefreshAll()
wb.api.update_link(Name="File_path")

Comment: If you want to update them during opening, simply set `update_links=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following code. this supposed to be work.

```
import xlwings
app = xlwings.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
app.display_alerts = False
```